# How to set bashrc file to make Ubuntu terminal to use my latest R installation?

Tags: r, path, rstudio

Given Ubuntu 18.04 laptop; Anaconda 1.9; R-Studio and R installed independently by myself without using Anaconda.

When I am going to Ubuntu terminal and hit:
`which R`:

> /home/company/anaconda3/bin/R

`R`:

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"....

`nano ~/.bashrc`:

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer

export PATH="/home/paygilant/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

# Added by me:

export PATH=/usr/lib/R/bin/R:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

SPARK_HOME=/home/ccc/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7

export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

R Studio uses latest R (3.5.2).

How do I "tell" Ubuntu to use the latest R version I have installed as first priority.

I suppose it's a PATH problem and priority.

Please advise.

Comment: /usr/lib/R/bin/R is almost certainly the actual R executable and thus you don't want *that* to be in your path - you want the folder containing it to be in your path.

Comment: @Dason then how do I change it right?

Comment: @Dason should I correct it to export PATH=/usr/lib/R/bin:$PATH?